# Can i put a date string in a cell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, date

i'm a bit stuck with a simple code : i'd like to put a clock inside a cell in my table View, is this possible? i've got this code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f 
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(updateTime:) 
                                   userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateTime:(id)sender{

    NSDate *StrDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *Dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [Dateformat setDateFormat:@"DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"];
    NSMutableString *DateStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Dateformat stringFromDate:StrDate]];

    string = DateStr;
}
```

in the .h file, i created :

> NSMutableString *string;

and in the cellForRow... method, i put :

> cell.textLabel.text = string;

so this does not work, can you explain me why?

thanks a lot

Comment: Looks right. Did you try making the string non mutable? i.e. `NSString`? Also where do you declare `string`?

Comment: @dasdom : what do you suggest for the Dateformat : an autorelease would work?

Comment: @Srikar : thanks, but even with NSString, it's the same : the cell won't show the text...

Comment: Make a `[Dateformat release];` after you have used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
NSMutableString *DateStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Dateformat stringFromDate:StrDate]];
```

you are creating an autoreleased mutable string. With

```
string = DateStr;
```

you assign the address of `string` to the address of `DateStr`. As `DateStr` is autoreleased this address will point to nowhere after the run loop finishes. You could either retain `DateStr` with

```
string = [DateStr retain];
```

or create a retained `DateStr` with

```
NSMutableString *DateStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[Dateformat stringFromDate:StrDate]];
```

But as string pointed to an address before with this you will again get a leak. Therefore you should make string a property

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *string;
```

and use the following code:

```
NSMutableString *DateStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Dateformat stringFromDate:StrDate]];

self.string = DateStr;
```

With the last line you are copying the string.

Comment: thanks dasdom, so i tried with the property, but the cells are still empty (i checked any mistake like numberofRows, or if the "type" of the ivar and property is different, but everything looks ok) . Same thing with "retain" on DateStr, but thanks for the explanation, it makes me understand more about that. Also, if there's a leak in a project, does it mean that my cell will NOT show the text in the cell? or it's just a wrong way to write the code, but the text will still appears in the cell? Finally, why do you use here "copy" instead of "retain" in the @prop? Thanks again

Comment: Have you set the number of sections to 1?

Comment: You should use copy instead of retain as you don't know whether the DateStr is changed afterwards. It's just for safety. A leak is bad because the memory of mobile devices is not infinity. Therefore leaks make apps crash.

Comment: i'll try to figure out. If someone knows how to solve it, please post here ;) i check this answer as the solution, because your message have been a great help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reload the data in you tableview: `[self.tableView reloadData]`. Do this after `string = DateStr;`

Comment: You are very bad with memory management, I suggest reading a little about this subject. Alloc/init + retain would retain it twice and you would probably have a leak.

Comment: Please remove this: `string = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] retain];string = DateStr;` because it is completely wrong. You are initializing a string, retain it and then assign the address of the string to a new address. Therefore you are creating a memory leak.

Comment: That's what I suggested in my answer (that I was indeed bad with memory management). I have edited my answer to avoid confusion of future readers of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning the string to the text field like this?

```
[cell.textField setStringValue: string];
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working, it says : Request for member 'textField' in something not a structure or union ...

Comment: One more thing to try... [cell.view.textField setStringValue: string];

Comment: This is assuming that cell is an instance or subclass of NSTableCellView.